# PDF content saving to database with navigation preserved

Tags: database, pdf

Gooday all.
I  am currently doing some research on the best ways you save pdf content in a database (as HTML content), with the ability to navigate using the table of content later on the front end when rendered as HTML.
The table of content could also have nested content. I am currently looking at saving the table of content as JSON data in the database, and pdf pages as separate columns in another table, but that wouldn't look like a good option as updating later wouldn't be straightforward.

Any pointer to resources and a proposed solution would be appreciated.

Comment: "the best ways you save pdf content in a database " - the best way is, don't ! Seriously. Store data that is relational in a database and non-relational in a file system.

Comment: @MitchWheat, so I think I wasn't clear enough in my question.

The current requirement is moving pdf content to the web for easy navigation. A table of content would be presented as a side menu of the web page to allow users to navigate easily through the contents. I am looking at saving each pdf page content as HTML, to allow editing/updating later.

However, I need insight into how the table of content would be saved/retrieved so that when a user clicks on a specific table of content the corresponding page/section of the page is displayed.